# How to stay with a percent of data from a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
CustomerId    Product
1             Apple
2             Orange
3             Apple
4             Watermelon
...           ...
1000          Apple
```

Suppose that I have 500 apples in the product column. I would like to stay with a DataFrame that contains 10% of the 500 apples (and 100% of the other categories, that is, I would like to have a DataFrame with 550 rows). Is there a way to do this efficiently? Can this 10% of apples left be chosen randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the apple rows:

```
apples = df["Product"] == 'Apple'
```

Randomly choose the rows to keep:

```
HOW_MANY = 0.1 # 10%
keep = np.random.binomial(1, HOW_MANY, size=apples.sum()).astype(bool)
```

Combine the non-apple rows and the apple rows to keep:

```
results = pd.concat([df[~apples], df[apples][keep]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [df.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) for this, which returns a random sample of items:

```
condition = df['Product'] != 'Apple'
df_all = df[condition] #This data frame has 100% of all products
df_apple = df[~condition]
percent = int(o.1*df_apple.shape[0]) # calculate 10% of Apple products
df_all = df_all.append(df_all.sample(percent)) #Append random items of apple to df_all
```

Of course, the number of dataframes can be decreased, more variables are used for better understanding.